# Java 8: Weird results combining instanceof and ternary operator

Tags: java, ternary-operator, instanceof

I am writing a method where all of its arguments will either be `double`s or `int`s.  Since much of the code will be the same inside for both overloads, I thought it would be easier to write the interface to accept `Number`s.

One of the things I need to do in this method is validate that one of the arguments is greater than zero.  To make it so I can `compare()` the passed value against zero, I have the following static fields:

```
private static final Double ZERO_D = Double.valueOf(0);
private static final Integer ZERO_I = Integer.valueOf(0);
```

In the method in question, I then try to execute this test:

```
Number zero = ((stepSize instanceof Double) ? ZERO_D : ZERO_I);
```

The strange thing is that this code ALWAYS sets `zero` to `ZERO_D`.

I currently am using the following code to successfully work around the issue:

```
Number zero;
if (stepSize instanceof Double) {
  zero = ZERO_D;
} else {
  zero = ZERO_I;
}
```

Could anyone explain why I am getting this strange result?  I would prefer to use the ternary operator here if I can.

Comment: What is `stepSize`? How do you tell what was assigned?

Comment: Your `ZERO_I` is a `Double`.  Shouldn't it be an `Integer`?

Comment: Create ten instances of `Double.valueOf(0)` and compare them using `==`.  They will all be the same.

Comment: @HotLicks `Double`, not `Integer`.

Comment: @Pokechu22: Thanks for catching that.  Unfortunately, that is not a bug in the actual code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: `stepSize` is a `Number` encapsualating either `1` or `0.05` right now.  I figure out which it is using the Eclipse debugger.

Comment: Just do `stepSize.getClass()` and check what it returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the ternary operator always evaluates to a single type, and in your case Java figures that given your second and third parameter, [the final type should be Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), and therefore it converts the Integer to match.

You can cast to make it return a `Number` instead:

```
Number zero = ((stepSize instanceof Double) ? (Number) ZERO_D : ZERO_I);
```

Comment: _so it autoconverts/boxes the int_ Which `int`?

Answer (score 0):

Both branches of a ternary operator must have the same type. According to section §15.25 of the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> If both the second and the third operand expressions are numeric expressions, the conditional expression is a numeric conditional expression.

And [section §15.25.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2) says:

> The type of a numeric conditional expression is determined as follows: [*several cases that don't apply to your code*] binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.

The widening rules in [section §5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) say:

> If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.

Thus, your `Integer` is unboxed, converted to `double`, and boxed into a `Double`, and the type of your numeric conditional expression is `Double`. (Actually, I'm not 100% certain. It may be that the type is `double`, and the boxing happens when that `double` is assigned to your `Number`.)